# Unable to increase token lifespan in keycloak per client

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

When I try to set the access token lifespan (or any time related field, really) for a client, it only works when the specified time is *lower* than the time specified in the realm settings.

Let's say I have set the *Access Token Lifespan*, *SSO Session Max* and *Client Session Max* all to 1 day in my realm settings.
I have two clients, one `public` and one`confidential`.

For the `public` client, 1 day is fine. But for the confidential client I want to increase the *Client Session Max* and *Access Token Lifespan* to e.g. 7 days. I set this under "Advanced Settings" in the client settings in the admin console. However, this doesn't work. The `expires_in` from the access token response will always be 86400 seconds.
If I *decrease* the client specific settings to, e.g. 10 minutes, it does work.

How can I increase the the Token lifespan per client? Is it even possible? If not, is this by design or maybe a bug? (I'm using Keycloak 15.0.2).

I'd expect it to work, as I want the realm to provide "maximum security" and then only lower it per client as a conscious decision (also, hovering the ?-icon says: "If not set, it uses the standard SSO Session Max value.")

Comment: Looking at the code, I’d say it’s by design.